# What is multi-party federation?

Tags: identity-management, federation

I am asked to prepare a write up on Identity Federation. I have nearly completed the write up. There is a term multi-party federation which I am confuesed at. Does it simply mean alloting multiple parties to carry out federation? Or is it a term that requires more research?

I couldn't see much articles in Google. A Google search for **multi party federation** returned only one valid result. Rest were regarding politics. Could you enlighten me regarding the topics with some introduction.

Comment: I believe it means that an entity belongs to multiple federations. Here is a PDF presentation on using OpenID Connect with multi-party federations: https://self-issued.info/presentations/OpenID_Connect_Federation_Japan_24-Jan-20.pdf You may want to include SAML or OpenID in your search terms.

Comment: " I have nearly completed the write up" - without knowing anything about the topic. Impressive.

Comment: Maybe because the correct term is federated identity.